# View Pager is not working in Fragment when it is running in worker thread

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

In Fragment, I am trying to load the data in view pager using worker thread. Same code is working when it is in activity, but in fragment is giving exception. In exception it is saying that in "doInBackground" is causing some problem. But in "doInBackground" I am just assigning data to some variable.

```
HTML5Test.java
==============

package com.example.asynctaskfra;



import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class HTML5Test extends Fragment {




    String[] displayDatainHTML5 = { "tstessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfeugiat, vitae consectetur","Checl something Nulla dolor ligula, 123456677777777","13232","312321313","e2324234324"};
    private ImageButton ViewPageReportLeft;
    private ImageButton ViewPageReportRight;
    private ImageButton showCalendar;
    private ImageButton sharing;
    private TextView showDate;
    private Handler m_handler;
    int count =5;
    String Format = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager viewPager;
    View convertView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.html5test, container, false);

        viewPager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Content);
        ViewPageReportLeft = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LeftArrow);
        ViewPageReportRight = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RightArrow);
        showCalendar = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Calendar);
        sharing = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Sharing);


        initControls();


        return convertView; 

    }



    private void initControls() {




        new BackGroundTask(viewPager).execute();    
    }


    ProgressDialog waitdialog;
    public  class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void ,Void>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              super.onPreExecute();
              //waitdialog=ProgressDialog.show(HTML5Content.this, "", "please wait data is loading");
              Log.d("Post Execute", "Is excuted");


        }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                count=displayDatainHTML5.length;
                return null;
            }
            @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                            viewPager.setAdapter(new TextPagerAdapter(getActivity(),displayDatainHTML5,Color.GREEN));
                            m_handler = new Handler();
                            startRepeatingTask();
                            //Pageindicator(0);
                            waitdialog.dismiss();


                }
       }


    private void adsRotation() {

        int cur=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if(cur==count-1){
            cur=0;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(cur);
        }
        else{
            cur=cur+1;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(cur);
        }

    }

    Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            adsRotation(); // this function can change value of m_interval.
            Log.d("Check" , "Whether it is running");
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker, 6000);
        }
    };

    void startRepeatingTask() {
        m_statusChecker.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
        m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_statusChecker);
    }


}


html5test.xml
=============

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TopImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.43"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="ShowDate" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Sharing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Blackline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:src="@drawable/blackline" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/OutputLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/Content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Blackline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:src="@drawable/blacklinethin" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/LeftArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Read"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="Read More Featured Stories" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/RightArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

TextPagerAdapter.java
=====================

package com.example.asynctaskfra;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TextPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    String [] displayData;
    int passColor;

    public TextPagerAdapter(Context context,String [] displayData,int passColor) {
        this.displayData=displayData;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);    
        this.context=context;
        this.passColor = passColor;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return displayData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, view, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.displaytxt);
        title.setText(displayData[position]);
        title.setTextColor(passColor);
        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }
}

list_single.xml
===============


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/displaytxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please replace  PagerAdapter to FragmentPagerAdapter it is work properly .

Comment: Thank you Nilesh for your response. I got it from where the error is coming. I commented Progress Dialog code because of which is exception is coming.